# Exporting Animation without IK targets, poles bones and other controls

Tags: animation, export, bones, inverse-kinematics

I've created a character that has been rigged with IKs constraints for legs and arms and some other custom controls implemented through other constraints applied on control bones (like a copy rotation that copies the rotation of a control bone on the spine bones with different weights for each bone).

I'm exporting this character to use it in a game engine and obviously, all the control bones are shown in the exported "skeleton". Is there a way to avoid some "secondary" bones to be exported? I'm only interested in the final animations I don't need to maintain the logic implemented through the constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pose mode you can select all bones you need and bake the animation into a new action, removing the constraints. The movements will be the same as if the constraints were still acting.

[image]